# Algorithm to define min-Max ranges with some defined bound

Tags: algorithms

Having to populate the following table of MIN-MAX cells, starting with only the knowledge of the **IC** value

[image]

I was thinking about a formula to get the values of **A, B, C, D, E, F, G**
which works also for the values of **IC** and **2xIC**

I'm able to get the values from **0** to **IC** using the following formula:

$$K = 3$$
$$LEVEL.MIN = \frac{IC}{K} \times (LEVEL-1)$$
$$LEVEL.MAX = \frac{IC}{K} \times (LEVEL)$$

I need another similar formula for the values of **E, F, G, 2xIC**.
Maybe, since $E=IC$, the formula should have $+IC$ as a fxed part.

Comment: What do the different levels mean? What is IC? So I understand that "MIN" is the minimum value of some set, and "MAX" is the maximum value of some set, but what are these sets? Could you give more context to your problem? And how did you obtain the formulae that you wrote?

Comment: Each level is a rang of economic values, and I have the IC value as input.
They are needed to know in which level to put an item based on its value.

Comment: Are there some conditions for the values of A, B, C, D, E, F, G .... ?

Comment: Each level from 1 to 3 needs to have the same width = max - min
Each level from 4 to 5 needs to have the same width = max - min
and Level[N].min = Level[N-1].max

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at the conditions that you gave. You say that the MIN of level $n$ should be equal to the MAX of level $n-1$. Using this condition, we should rename the variables like so:

- Level 1: MIN = 0, MAX = A
- Level 2: MIN = A, MAX = D
- Level 3: MIN = D, MAX = E= IC
- Level 4: MIN = E, MAX = G
- Level 5: MIN = G, MAX = 2IC = 2E

The next condition is that each level from 1 to 3 needs to have the same difference between MAX and MIN. In other words,
$$
A = D-A = IC-D
$$
From this condition we see that $D = 2A$ and of course $$A=IC-D \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad D = 2IC - 2D \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad 3D=2IC$$
The next condition is that levels 4 and 5 need to have the same difference between MAX and MIN. In other words,
$$
G-E = 2E - G
$$
Adding $E+G$ to boths sides, this is the same as $2G = 3E$. Now we can plug in these results to get the new level hierarchy:

- Level 1: MIN = $0$, MAX = $A$
- Level 2: MIN = $A$, MAX = $2A$
- Level 3: MIN = $2A$, MAX = $IC$
- Level 4: MIN = $IC$, MAX = $\frac{3}{2} IC$
- Level 5: MIN = $\frac{3}{2} IC$, MAX = $2IC$

With these conditions, the hierarchy is left with two free variables, IC and A. But otherwise, the hierarchy now follows the conditions that you gave.

Comment: $$A=\frac{IC}{K}=\frac{IC}{3}$$
I think I found the equivalent formula for the other values.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally got it.

[image]

The values from **E to 2xIC** can be calculated using the following formula:
$$W=2$$
$$LEVEL.MIN = \frac{LEVEL-1-1}{W} \times IC$$
$$LEVEL.MAX = \frac{LEVEL-1}{W} \times IC$$